# JsonPath that combines fields from a complex object

Tags: jsonpath

I am using jsonpath_rw_ext for python currently

I am unable to come up with a path string that returns the fields I want without getting errors.
I think I can get most of what I'm describing as individual fields however I can't put then together.

json object is an array of two objects:

```
[
{
    'id': 9707,
    'rev': 16,
    'fields': {
        'System.AssignedTo': {
            'id': 12345
            'descriptor': 'some-identifier',
            'displayName': 'Jeff Saremi',
        },
        'System.CommentCount': 7
},
{
    'id': 9708,
    'rev': 10,
    'fields': {
        'System.AssignedTo': {
            'id': 56789
            'descriptor': 'another-identifier',
            'displayName': 'Someone Else',
        },
        'System.CommentCount': 2
}
]
```

What I want in the results is:
id (the topmost level one), fields.`System.CommentCount` and fields `System.AssignedTo`.displayName

I do not want deeper "id" levels

Here are what i have tried individually:

```
jp.match('$[*].id', workitems)

returns the toplevel IDs
```

```
jp.match('$..fields["System.CommentCount"]', workitems)

returns the commentcounts promptly
```

```
jp.match('$..fields..displayName', workitems)

returns the displayNames
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this cannot be done not with the library I'm using.

I had to create 3 separate lists and `zip` then together to have one coherent resultset.